# How to call a function depending on the radio button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions and i want to call one function when the radio button is checked as an employee and the other when the radio button is checked as a user.

```
employee.form.send = function() {
   employee.validator.checkForm();
   if (employee.validator.valid()) {

    employee.form.submit();
   }
  };


 invite.form.send = function() {
   invite.validator.checkForm();
   if (invite.validator.valid()) {
    alert(1);
     invite.form.submit();
   }
 }
```

I would normally call them with a click event like this

```
invite.find('#sendInviteButton').on('click',invite.form.send);
```

Now i want to call different functions when the `#sendInviteButton` is clicked. Depending on the radio button selected. How do i do that? 
I am not able to call the `invite.form.send inside` an if condition.

Answer (score 0):

what about binding the event to a function which checks the state of the ratio button and than depending on that call the proper functions accordingly? (Check code below)

---

```
invite.find('#sendInviteButton').on('click', checkState); // update the event binding
```

---

```
function checkState() {
    if (document.getElementById('sendInviteButton').checked) {
        // call function if #sendInviteButton is checked
    } else {
        // call other function
    }
}
```

or in case you use jQuery:

```
function checkState() {
    if($('#sendInviteButton').is(':checked')) {
        // call function if #sendInviteButton is checked
    } else {
       // call other function
    }
}
```

Comment: I have my function like this `employee.form.send = function() {
   employee.validator.checkForm();
   if (employee.validator.valid()) {

    employee.form.submit();
   }
  }` and i am nt able to call this like `employee.form.send`

Comment: you have to call it with: `employee.form.send()` ...
or sorry if I misunderstand, but I don't get what you want to tell/ask me with that

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
    if($('#employee_radio_button').is(':checked'))
         employee.form.send();
    else
         invite.form.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the click into a function with jQuery like so, assuming your function names are "oneFunction" and "anotherFunction"..

```
$('#sendInviteButton').click(function() { 
 if ($('#sendInviteButton').is(':checked')) {
   oneFunction();
  } else {
   anotherFunction();
  }
});
```